# Fragment gives null object reference on layout inflater

Tags: android

I have a fragment "data" class which receives an array of string from the main activity class and sets those strings as textview inside itself. 
I have a function "set" which receives string array as parameters and sets that as textview. 
 Code for fragment "data" class is -

```
public class data extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.data,container,false);
        return v;
    }

    public void set(String[] a){

        LayoutInflater li=(LayoutInflater)getActivity().getLayoutInflater() // Logcat gives error at this line 
        View v=li.inflate(R.layout.data,null);
        TextView t1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView t2=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        t1.setText(a[0]);
        t2.setText(a[1]);

    }
 }
```

Log cat error is -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.LayoutInflater android.app.Activity.getLayoutInflater()' on a null object reference
```

*****EDIT******
Now I am passing data using bundles instead of String array-
My data class looks like this-
public class data extends Fragment {

```
TextView t1,t2;
    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.data,container,false);
         t1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
         t2=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        return v;
    }

    public void set(){


        t1.setText(getArguments().getString("name"));
        t2.setText(getArguments().getString("email"));

    }
}
```

I am calling this set like this from my main activity

```
show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ public void onClick(View v){
            FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            data frag=new data();
            ft.add(R.id.ly2,frag);
            ft.commit();
            String s[]=data.show();
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putString("name",s[0]);
            b.putString("email",s[1]);
            frag.setArguments(b);
            frag.set();

        }});<br><br>
```

My show function is inside another class that uses database-

```
public String[] show(){
        String[] col={"name","email"};
        Cursor c=sdb.query("book",col,null,null,null,null,null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        String d[]=new String[2];
        d[0] =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
        d[1] =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("email"));
        return d;
        }
```

Logcat now says-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Kindly help.

Comment: You probably call `set(String[] a)` method before the fragment gets added to the activity thus its method `getActivity()` returns null. I have no idea why you would use a layout inflater again in the set method in the fragment to inflate another layout of the same type. Just retrieve the views in the `onViewCreated` method and use thrm in the `set(String[] a)` method

Comment: Previously I had been calling set() before adding fragment but now that I have done the correction it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Yup. But it gives me out of scope error in method get()

Comment: Please provide logcat and your code

Comment: where is your 'get' method ...? you only have 'set' method ?

Comment: It doesn't has a get method. I am setting values in it from the main activity.

Comment: @MatBos I did as miriana said. But it now gives a new error.   
Sorry miriana my mistake. Yup they aren't out of scope but now gives a new error. <br> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: Please check the edited question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `set()` before the fragment has been attached to the activity.

---

**UPDATE**: In your edited question, you are still calling `set()` before the fragment has been attached to the activity. `commit()` on a `FragmentTransaction` is asynchronous; work on attaching the fragment to the activity will not begin until after you return control of the main application thread back to the framework.

Comment: Previously I had been calling set() before adding fragment but now that I have done the correction it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @Shivamaggarwal: Then you are still calling it before the fragment has been attached to the activity.

Comment: @Shivamaggarwal: I have updated my answer to reflect your updated question.

Comment: Alright. But sir how should I do this. I can't find any way to do this now .

Comment: @Shivamaggarwal: Move your two remaining lines from `set()` into `onCreateView()`. Then, get rid of `set()` and the call to `set()`. Also, I would recommend attaching the arguments `Bundle` to the fragment before doing anything with the fragment in a `FragmentTransaction`, though *probably* how you are doing it will hold up.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class data extends Fragment {
    TextView t1;
    TextView t2;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.data,container,false);
           t1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        t2=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        return v;
    }

    public void set(String[] a){
        t1.setText(a[0]);
        t2.setText(a[1]);

    }
 }
```

You do not need to inflate the layout twice in a fragment.

Comment: How come out of the scope?

Comment: they are not out of scope, they are class variables?

Comment: But once they are initialized I am assuming they are no longer null. So once the fragment is in view the textviews are accessible.

Comment: Sorry miriana my mistake. Yup they aren't out of scope but now gives a new error. <br>            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: I am guessing the textView is null. Are you are you are trying to access the function after the fragment is in view and also double check the xml for mismatch ids. Mismatch ids sometimes cause this error.

Comment: the set() is being called before the fragment is in focus. That is the reason for null pointer exception

Comment: So how should I correct this code now . Please help

Comment: Got it !!!. I must call get inside the onCreateView method of fragment. It works now. :)

Comment: I was editing the answer :P . Please answer your own question or accept the answer that best helped so that it would benefit the community. Happy coding

Comment: Anytime. Glad to help. Happy Coding